# Problems with Android and Eclipse Functionality

Tags: android, eclipse

I am coming from XCode and iOS development to Android.  Downloaded the sdk right from here [http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV2GN.png).  It seems to be very unstable and things don't work, IE dragging a textclock into the activity, which I need, throws a null reference exception with no guidance on what is wrong and layouts not staying lined up when I move something or make a seemingly trivial change.  Very mind numbing and frustrating at this point, almost to the point where I feel like I set it up wrong or that there is an issue with it.  Does anyone know if this might be the case or if there is a link that describes the gotchas with Eclipse and Android and how to get through them without smashing a mouse and keyboard first?

Below is a screen of what happens after dragging in a TextClock.  A also opened the details window.

[image]

Comment: Since dragging and dropping a `TextClock` does not generally cause a problem, please edit your question. Remove the rants, and replace them with an exact description of your symptoms, including screenshots of where this "null reference exception" is coming from.

Comment: No rant intended whatsoever.  It sounds worse than I mean it, but have also had a horrible experience so far.  Added a screen shot.  All i did was drag it in and the only way out is to use undo.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your specific problem -- I even tried dragging a `TextClock` into a `RelativeLayout`. If you're in position to create a reproducible test case, you're welcome to post it to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list Note that `TextClock` is new to Android 4.2 (API Level 17), and so unless your app is going to be only used on very new devices, you're going to want to come up with another solution anyway, or else try to backport `TextClock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very bad question and I voted to close it.

However, it's a good (if obvious) observation. Yes, the tooling sucks. The main problem is - each upgrade of each element (Eclipse, ADT, SDK) brings new problems and gotchas, so you cannot really find out about the workarounds and just get on with your work. You have to learn to live with the occasional surprises and the constant feeling of bewilderment and instability.

The relatively good news is that after a couple of months you will develop (no pun intented) an intuition for how things work, what usually helps, which problems require a mere project refresh (the magic F5 key!), what can be fixed with restarting eclipse, cleaning the project or just turning the logcat view on and off...

Comment: Agreed, its a bad question in hindsight.  Knowing it is how it is and not somehow broken makes me feel a little better though.  Thx!

Comment: Glad I could help, if only emotionally. You HAVE tried F5, cleaning project and restarting Eclipse? :-)

Comment: Never tried F5, but have gotten used to cleaning the project before running on the emulator and it seems to fix a lot of the little goofs that pop up.  I will try your suggestion and see if it helps at all.  Thx, appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't spend too much time with the GUI element of Eclipse ADT, it is a mess. If you want smooth IDE, you are probably better off with Android Studio even though it is still in early phase. If you are just starting out with Android, might as well go with Android Studio and gradle since it is the future direction for Android.

Comment: I take it there are Eclipse fans around. I use Eclipse for a lot of other purpose (pojo dev, cdt, pydev..etc) but ADT has always been a crap shoot. The disconnected build system between ADT and command line is crazy headache when you try to build app that grow beyond one single project (try multi tier library dependency).